# How to manage complex user abilities in Rails with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I am trying to create a web app, where users have a dashboard where they can opt into a number of widgets. I have the following many-to-many:

```
class CreateWidgets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :widgets do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :users_widgets, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :widget, index: true
    end
  end    
end
```

With a users model defined by the devise gem. So how can I most effectively set up some parameters which allow me to define the users ability to only see widgets they have "subscribed" to.

CanCan permissions are defined here:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, Widget, :user_id => user.id
  end
end
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, as there is no parameter to track which user created the widget. So How would I set up the Widget / User models? Possibly add a list of entitlements to the user model? It could be a whole load of bool attributes, one for each type of  widget, but obviously, that might get a bit messy, how should I tackle this in a security conscious way?

## Update:

My models now read:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :widgets, through: :subscriptions
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :widget
  # make sure you add a unique DB index as well.
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :widget_id
end
```

and my `model/ability.rb` file reads:

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
        can :read, Widget do |widget|
            widget.subscriptions.where(user: user).any?
        end
    end
end
```

But it still doesn't work, I expect this is due to the note about unique db index note, but I am not sure what to add for this?

Answer (score 3):

You would first need to create a [many to many join model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) between User and Widget.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :widgets, through: :subscriptions
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :widget
  # make sure you add a unique DB index as well.
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :widget_id
end
```

You would then authorize by passing a block to `can`:

```
can :read, Widget do |widget|
  widget.subscriptions.where(user: user).any?
end
```

Comment: I have posted my migration files, presumably I add something to them?

Comment: The unique database index simply ensures that you don't have duplicates in your `subscriptions` table. You would add one with `add_index(:subscriptions, [:user_id, :widget_id], unique: true)`. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Comment: "Obviously, this doesn't work, as there is no parameter to track which user created the widget." - that was not even in the original question. The simplest way to do this would be add a `belongs_to :creator, class: 'User'` and a `creator_id` column to Widget (you can call it whatever you want).

Comment: thanks. The thing is that the users don't create the widgets, they just subscribe to them, so many users can be subscribed to the same widget.

Comment: Yeah you would use the relationship above, you might want to start by reading the guides article and figuring out how relationships work in rails. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I understand the relationship, just not how to define what I need to for cancan authorisation

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I have given you the tools you need - but you don't seem to grasp the concepts involved at all. You need to setup a m2m relation, which you then can query in the block passed to `can`. I'm not sure how to help you more as you don't have a very coherent description of how you actually want the auth logic to work.

Comment: Hi Max, well what would the unique db index reference be?

Comment: `add_index :subscriptions, [:user_id, :widget_id], unique: true`